# SQL - Query to find the number of entries in a given category

Tags: sql, count

I'm looking to create a query that will return of list of each "category" in a table along with the number of entries in that category. For example, if I had a table with the following data:

```
ID    Category     Value
1     A            7
2     B            12
3     A            34
4     C            2
5     C            7
6     A            4
```

The query should return:

```
Category     Count
A            3
B            1
C            2
```

I know I would go about achieving this if I made the query specifically look for these 3 categories, however, I want to make it work with a unknown set of categories. In other words, if I added an entry to the table with category D or some other name, the same code would return the list with a category of the new name containing 1 count.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(1) FROM Table GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: Great, that's much more simple than I was expecting it'd be. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select category, count(*) from t
group by category
```